# C++ - Arduino - no matching function for call to

Tags: c++, arduino

I do have 2 simple classes in an Arduino Project.:

The classes were put in Point.h and Line.h files.

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#ifndef Point_h
#define Point_h

class Point{

    public:
        Point(int x);
        int getPunkt();
        void setPunkt(int x);

    private:
        int _x;
};

/////////////////////////////////
Point::Point(int x){
    _x = x;
}

int Point::getPunkt(){
    return _x;
}

void Point::setPunkt(int x){
    _x = x;
}
#endif
```

And:

```
#include "Point.h"
#ifndef Line_h
#define Line_h

class Line{

public:
    Line(Point p1, Point p2);

private:
    Point _p1;
    Point _p2;
};

Line::Line(Point p1, Point p2){
    _p1 = p1;
    _p2 = p2;
}

#endif
```

The constructor of Line gives me:

**Multiple markers at this line
    - candidates are:
    - no matching function for call to 'Point::Point()'**

What am I doing wrong? This is just a simple example.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use [member initializer lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) **from now on**. `_p1` and `_p2` have to be default constructed first (if you omit the member initializer list):

```
Line::Line(Point p1, Point p2) : _p1(), _p2() { ... }
```

to do the assignments later in the constructor's body. (`Point` does not have default constructor generated, because you've provided your own.)

You have to do this:

```
Line::Line(Point p1, Point p2) : _p1(p1), _p2(p2) {} // copy-initialize
```

(Do the same for `Point::Point`.)

Comment: thank you very much. I didnt knew about this concept. Its completly new to me. But I will erad you Link. Thank you very much. This cost me a night. :-)

Comment: You're welcome, but rather read the duplicate post first.

Comment: Yeah I googled it on this site but didnt found the answer. But sorry for double posted question.